# How to add easing to this animation

Tags: jquery

Here is an existing function to scroll to my div anchors , but i'd like to use easing instead , I have no idea how to edit this to add , i've tried a few things but nothing has worked

I tried this

```
  $.fn.anchorAnimate.defaults = {
    speed: 600,
    offset: -65,
    easing:"easeOutCubic"
  };
```

Here is existing function

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.anchorAnimate = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.anchorAnimate.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var caller = this;
      $(caller).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href");

        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top + settings.offset;
        $("html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
          if(0 === settings.offset) {
            window.location.hash = elementClick;
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  };

  $.fn.anchorAnimate.defaults = {
    speed: 600,
    offset: -65
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: did you try the easing option of animate? .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension does not use any easing settings on the `.animate()` function. You can add it like this:

```
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, settings.easing, function() {
    // bla bla
});
```

... and this:

```
$.fn.anchorAnimate.defaults = {
    speed: 600,
    offset: -65,
    easing: "swing"
};
```

... but the problem is, there is no `easeOutCubic` available in jQuery. Check that:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins,
>   most notably the jQuery UI suite.

Related jQuery article [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing).

jQuery UI easing [here](http://jqueryui.com/easing/).

jQuery UI custom download easing only [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4&components=0000000000000000000001000000000000000).